# how to add a default value to the column in a Oracle database table using trigger?

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers

I have a customers table with following columns:

```sql
CREATE TABLE customers
  (
    customer_id NUMBER 
                GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY START WITH 320 
                PRIMARY KEY,
    name         VARCHAR2( 255 ) NOT NULL,
    address      VARCHAR2( 255 )         ,
    website      VARCHAR2( 255 )         ,
    credit_limit NUMBER( 8, 2 )          ,
    isActive VARCHAR2(20) /*values are either TRUE or FALSE(default)*/
  );
```

there are already many records in this table and now I wanted to write a trigger so when a new customer row is inserted, the `isActive` should be defaulted to `FALSE`.

I did something like this:

```sql
CREATE or REPLACE TRIGGER "UPDATE_ACTIVE_STATUS" BEFORE INSERT ON CUSTOMERS
FOR EACH ROW
when (NEW.CUSTOMER_ID > 0)
BEGIN
UPDATE CUSTOMERS set NEW.ISACTIVE = 'FALSE';
dbms_output.put('updated flag: ' || new.ISACTIVE);
END;
```

but I get the following error:

```
Error: SQL statement ignored  
Error: ORA-00904: NEW.ISACTIVE invalid identifier  
Error: NEW.ISACTIVE must be declared
```

I am just trying to set  default value for `isActive` column before insert and unable to successfully do it. Also looking to see if I need to add any other validations.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: :NEW  instead of NEW

Comment: I updated all New to :New and getting ```invalid use of bind variable in trigger when clause```

Comment: Why a trigger? You could `alter table customers modify inactive default on null 'FALSE'`. Though `'TRUE'` and `'FALSE'` seem rather verbose ways of representing `'Y'` and `'N'`.

Comment: Pointed it out in my answer too. However, it's not clear what exactly @happytohelp tries to achieve. If there is already some code in the wild that inserts 'TRUE', and they need to override it, then default value is of no help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDIT: you don't need a trigger for this task

```
ALTER TABLE CUSTOMER MODIFY isActive VARCHAR2(20) DEFAULT 'FALSE';
```

Don't try to *update* the same table inside trigger - you'll get a "mutating table" error. Just modify pseudorecord :NEW

```
CREATE or REPLACE TRIGGER "UPDATE_ACTIVE_STATUS"
BEFORE INSERT ON CUSTOMERS
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF :NEW.CUSTOMER_ID > 0 THEN
        :NEW.ISACTIVE := 'FALSE';
    END IF;
    dbms_output.put('updated flag: ' || :new.ISACTIVE);
END;
```

And if you whant to use WHEN clause, remember that

> The NEW and OLD keywords, when specified in the WHEN clause, are not considered bind variables, so are not preceded by a colon (:). However, you must precede NEW and OLD with a colon in all references other than the WHEN clause. So

```
CREATE or REPLACE TRIGGER "UPDATE_ACTIVE_STATUS"
BEFORE INSERT ON CUSTOMERS
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN (NEW.CUSTOMER_ID > 0)
BEGIN
    :NEW.ISACTIVE := 'FALSE';
    dbms_output.put('updated flag: ' || :new.ISACTIVE);
END;
```

Comment: I think IF :NEW.CUSTOMER_ID > 0 instead of IF :NEW.CUSTOMER_ID > O right?

Comment: Well, of cause > 0. Just mistyped

Comment: By the way, do you really need that condition: CUSTOMER_ID > 0? Are you going to insert rows with zero or negative CUSTOMER_ID?

Comment: we donot insert 0 or negative customer ids

Comment: _"we donot insert 0 or negative customer ids"_   Then there is no need to test it before proceeding.  Also, why is the column ISACTIVE a varchar2(20) when the only possible values are 'TRUE' (4 characters) or 'FALSE' (5 characters)?  Why not just CHAR(1), with values of 'T' or 'F'.    And a check constraint on it to prevent invalid values?

Comment: @EdStevens `varchar2(1)`, surely?

Comment: @WilliamRobertson - for anything larger than a single character, yes, varchar2.  But for a single character? Why not?  Just a nit, yes, and I wouldn't get my panties in wad if someone insisted on varchar2 for a single character column.  But for a single character indicator column like this, a simple CHAR(1) just appeals to my personal sense.  When I see CHAR(1) I think 'ah, an indicator with a limited set of acceptable values'.

Comment: @EdStevens surely the clue is in the `(1)` regardless? I appreciate your T/F constraint would rule out unexpected blanks (though maybe `active_yn` with allowed values of Y/N might be more readable), but I still think it opens the door to blank-padding bugs. I do wish we could have a [Boolean type for columns](https://community.oracle.com/tech/apps-infra/discussion/4385421/new-type-boolean) though.

Comment: Though I prefer CHAR(1) for "boolean", there's no real difference over VARCHAR2(1). See: [link](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:::::P11_QUESTION_ID:123212348063)


A CHAR datatype and VARCHAR2 datatype are stored identically (eg: the word 'WORD' stored in a CHAR(4) and a varchar2(4) consume exactly the same amount of space on disk, both have leading byte counts).